# how to drop dataframes from pyspark to manage memory?

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory, pyspark

I list my dataframes to drop unused ones. First I used below function to list dataframes that I found from one of the post

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def list_dataframes():

    return [k for (k, v) in globals().items() if isinstance(v, DataFrame)]
```

Then I tried to drop unused ones from the list. Code I used below

```
df2.unpersist()
```

When I list again df2 is still there. How can I drop the dataframes to have some memory on pyspark? or do you have any other suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Is this also helpful? df2.cache()

Comment: Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion. If you would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall out of the cache, use the RDD.unpersist() method. Does not make sense but try this, df1.rdd.unpersist()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using the latest or older spark you can use df.unpersist() to achieve the same but the older versions have a bug which is fixed in the latest version(2.3.2) of spark where its not updating the storage memory stats it works but its not updating the stats so i request you to run it on the latest spark to see the stats difference

Refer the below link to know more about this

[unpersist() issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24889)

[ReleaseNote for 2.3.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12315420&version=12343289)

Please do approve the answer if useful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me what does unpersist and cahce do ? If I do the cache and unpersist the dataframe, I do have more memory? Can you explain?Thank you

Comment: If you can ask a new question regarding this it would be helpful for others as this is not related to the asked question directly, but as you asked hope this link would help you out -> https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-caching.html